# My HTML page loads external HTML containing Javascript. How do I execute this Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I have a use case where a html page needs to load the contents of an external html file. The external html file contains html elements and Javascript code.

I want to make use of both html and the Javascript.

I can load and render the html contents, but how do I execute the Javascript in the external file? In this example I want to call `staticLoaded`

Note - I do not want to use any frameworks, ideally looking to achieve this in native js.

HTML file:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div id="content-here"></div>
     <script>
      function main(){    
        fetch('/file-location/')
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (html) {
          const contentHereDiv = document.getElementById("content-here");
          contentHereDiv.innerHTML = html;
        });
     }
     main();
     </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

External file:

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div>Hello world</div>
       <script>
          function staticLoaded(){
              console.log('Hello world');
          }
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="content-here">
  </div>
  <script>
    function main() {
      fetch('/example-page.html')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(html) {
          const contentHereDiv = document.getElementById("content-here");
          contentHereDiv.innerHTML = html;
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
        });
    }
    main();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Following suggestions. I came to the following solution.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="content-here">  
  </div>
  <script>
    function main(){    
      fetch('/example.html')
      .then(function (response) {
          console.log('respond');
          return response.text();
      })
      .then(function (html) {
        const contentHereDiv = document.getElementById("content-here");
        contentHereDiv.innerHTML = html;
        console.log('render content');
      })
      .then(() => {
        const staticScript = document.getElementById("static-js").innerHTML;    
        const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        scriptElement.innerText = staticScript;
        const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        head.appendChild(scriptElement);
        console.log('move script to head');
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('call function');
        staticLoaded();
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    }

    main();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have that external HTML file only for that script purpose?

Comment: @connexo no I would like to render the HTML and execute the JavaScript  contained in the script element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dealing with the same issue with payment provider. I solved it with something like that. You need to extract the script tag from your external file and you can use the following code later.

```
const data = '<script type="text/javascript">console.log("Hello!")</script>';
const cleanedData = data.split('<script type="text/javascript">').join('').split('</script>').join('\n');
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
scriptElement.innerText = cleanedData;
head.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Make sure **'data'** variable is coming from somewhere **safe**!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It gets me much closer to the solution. Thanks